# Modify Date clause

Tags: sql

The script attached is a monthly report, only has 1 month data. I want it to be ​from 2/1/2016 through 12/31/2016. Thanks in Advance for your help.

```
                    Floor (( Add_months(Trunc(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 1) - 
                           A.service_dt ) / 365.25) 
                                         "Years of Service", 

    WHERE  ( A.effdt = (SELECT Max(A_ED.effdt) 

                        WHERE  A.emplid = A_ED.emplid 

                               AND A_ED.effdt <= SYSDATE) 

                                    AND A.effdt = A_ES.effdt) 
             AND Extract(month FROM A.service_dt) = Extract(month FROM SYSDATE)
```

Comment: This isn't valid SQL (missing a SELECT) , and you need to show what you've already tried. And add your RDBMS flavor

Answer (score 1):

Just change the last line in WHERE clause to reflect the period you need. So instead of:

```
AND Extract(month FROM A.service_dt) = Extract(month FROM SYSDATE)
```

use

```
AND A.service_dt >= '2016-02-01' AND A.service_dt < '2017-01-01'
```

Note that I am using less than 01/01/2017 to capture time up to midnight on New Year's eve.